# Chrome extension - Is it possible to capture print dialog Print and Cancel button clicks?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In chrome, when we use Ctrl+P, print dialog will open. Here I want to record whether user has clicked on "Print" or on "Cancel". I know that there is no direct way of doing it through web application, I am thinking to implement with Chrome extensions (if there is a way). I am checking Print related APIs, but I don't find any related method to handle this scenario. Also how to attach event to the print, cancel (no proper ID or class names to these buttons) buttons which are loading in Shadow DOM.
Below are the URLs that I am verifying

[chrome.printing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/printing/)

Comment: No, extensions can't see into own UI of the browser.

Comment: Or any other way to capture those button clicks?